# gcc struct initialization slow assembly output?

Tags: c, gcc

given the following test program compiled with `gcc 5.3.1` and `-Ofast`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct foo {
    uint8_t b[8];
    uint64_t q;
} data[256];

int main(void)
{
    unsigned i;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        data[i] = (struct foo){{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 0};

    return 0;
}
```

the generated assembly code copies the 8 bytes of the struct using 8 movb instructions instead of a single movq instruction. This seems to be some sort of intended behavior because when all the values are 0 or when copying the struct it uses a single movq instruction to write the 8 bytes, but I couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked it to see if it's really slower?

Comment: There's no doubt that it is slower, probably not enough to have an impact in most cases though

Comment: Locality may make a difference. Copying with `movq` requires accessing the source memory area, which may cause a cache miss. The current sequence of instructions with immediate data is guranteed to be in cache.

Comment: @Barmar: What source memory area? `movq` can use an immediate, just like `movb`. I suspect the reason it behaves the way described is because the standard, [per cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) "The members of the current object are initialized in their natural order, unless designators are used (since C99): array elements in subscript order, struct members in declaration order, only the first declared member of any union." So the standard sorta kinda say that initialization should have predictable ordering.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think that's just talking about how it determines which element of the initialization expression corresponds to each element of the structure, not the timing of the initializations. And `movq` would move them in declaration order, wouldn't it?

Comment: It may very well just be an optimization that `gcc` doesn't know how to do.  You could file a bug report.